# how to complete arbitrary basis knowing 2 orthonormal vectors of Rd (d > 2)

Tags: linear-algebra

In a paper the following statement is used: "To construct the matrix B, complete the vectors (y, x) to an arbitrary basis of Rd and then apply the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalisation".

assume we know x and y.

Question:how to complete the 2 vectors to arbitrary basis in Rd?

(Rd is the dimensionality of the space)

Comment: Theoretically? Then it doesn't matter, completion exists. Practically? Choose random vectors. Anyway: Not suited here, better for math.SE.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is migrated to math.SE, I turn my comment into an answer.

From the theoretical side, there is no problem, since there exists an extension. To see this, consider the orthogonal complement of the space spanned by $x$ and $y$. It is itself a vector space (of dimension $d-2$). This vector space has a basis, as any vector space has.

Practically, one could choose $d-2$ random vectors $x_1,\dots,x_{d-2}$ (e.g. be choosing each coordinate following a Gaussian distribution). This will give (together with $x$ and $y$) a basis of $\mathbf{R}^d$ with probability one: The vector $x_1$ will be in $\mathrm{span}(x,y)$ probability zero (since $\mathrm{span}(x,y)$ is a Null set for the chosen distribution) and the same is true for $x_2$ w.r.t. $\mathrm{span}(x,y,x_1)$, and so forth…